# How to straighten the transition relations of an automaton in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}
\tikzset{
    initial text=\(\ast\),
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',thick, node distance=3cm]
        \node[state, initial] (q0) {$q_0$};
        \node[state, accepting, right of=q0] (q1) {$q_1$};

        \draw (q1) edge[loop above] node{$1$} (q1);
        \draw [->] (q0) edge[bend left, above] node{$0$} (q1);
        \draw [->] (q1) edge[bend left, below] node{$1$} (q0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: automaton without straight transition relation]

I want it to look something like this:

[image: automaton with straight transition relation]

Is there any way to get it?

Thanks `:D`!

Comment: Ti*k*Z only bends the arrows if you tell it to, i.e. you may want to remove the `bend left` directive. However, you'll probably also need to shift the arrows then such that they do not coincide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to draw from the `north east` / `south east` anchors of the relevant nodes.

If you want to make the lines closer together, you can also use the angular anchors for the nodes

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}
\tikzset{
    initial text=\(\ast\),
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',thick, node distance=3cm]
        \node[state, initial] (q0) {$q_0$};
        \node[state, accepting, right of=q0] (q1) {$q_1$};

        \draw (q1) edge[loop above] node{$1$} (q1);
        \draw  (q0.north east) edge[->, above] node{$0$} (q1.north west);
        \draw (q1.south west) edge[->, below] node{$1$} (q0.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',thick, node distance=3cm]
        \node[state, initial] (q0) {$q_0$};
        \node[state, accepting, right of=q0] (q1) {$q_1$};

        \draw (q1) edge[loop above] node{$1$} (q1);
        \draw  (q0.20) edge[->, above] node{$0$} (q1.160);
        \draw (q1.200) edge[->, below] node{$1$} (q0.340);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: When I zoom the figure I note that the two lines are not "straight" ... If I remove the double stroke (the node of the accepted state, named `q_1`) the lines are perfectly straight. Could this be improved?

Comment: @manooooh I'm not sure I understand. If I zoom the PDF to 1000x they still seem straight to me.  If you mean that the line doesn't overlap exactly with the q_0, the you can add `shorten <=-.5pt` to the draw options.

Comment: Sorry, I'm half obsessive with visual style. I attached an [image](https://imgur.com/a/EILRF) with your first example (north east / south east anchors) and without arrows (I removed the `->` to both nodes) along with a straight red line so that it appreciates that left end of the line of above is below the right end. With the bottom line it happens the other way around.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

... and if you want asymmetric shifts, or, more generally, custom shifts, consider

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata,calc}
\tikzset{
    initial text=\(\ast\),
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',thick, node distance=3cm]
        \node[state, initial] (q0) {$q_0$};
        \node[state, accepting, right of=q0] (q1) {$q_1$};

        \draw (q1) edge[loop above] node{$1$} (q1);
        \draw [->] ($(q0.east)+(0,11pt)$) -- node[above]{$0$} ($(q1.west)+(0,11pt)$);
        \draw [->] ($(q1.west)+(0,-3pt)$) -- node[below]{$1$} ($(q0.east)+(0,-3pt)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]